# Can i use celery without django

Tags: python, django, celery

I have API code which adds tasks to queue and then celery workers consuming those tasks.

Currently I have both code base same. But i want celery workers just to have simple plain Python tasks and no django code as workers will only be processing tasks and does not need django for that. Is it possible.

In order to start celery worker i need to use this line

```
celery -A django_project worker --queue high
```

What should i write instead of django_project there

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can.  Celery is a generic asynchronous task queue. In place of "django_project" you would point to your module.  See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#application for an example.

Here is an example project layout using celery:

```
project-dir/
    mymodule/
         __init__.py 
         celery.py
         tasks.py
    tests/
    setup.py
    etc, etc (e.g. tox.ini, requirements.txt, project management files)
```

In mymodule/celery.py:

```
# -*- coding : utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import Celery

app = Celery('mymodule',
             broker='amqp://',
             backend='amqp://',
             include=['mymodule.tasks'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

In mymodule/tasks.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from mymodule.celery import app

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Comment: what should be the contents of celery.py

Comment: How to run these tasks now?

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely use Celery without using any web framework like Django or Flask. Just create the Celery object and your tasks accordingly and run the following command

```
celery -A filename.celery_object_name worker --loglevel=info
```

Later, just run the Python file. You don't need to set anything. It works exactly with or without any Web Framework.